# Azure Bot Framework composer - ways to save conversation to Blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-bot-service

I am new to Bot Framework composer and looking for option to save all chat conversation (occurred in either Teams or web Channel), Is there a way to update settings on bot composer or from Azure Portal to save all chat into Blob Storage?,

I have seen option in Bot framework SDK V4, but cant find options in Bot composer V4

Also, If I have already published my Bot to Azure, using Bot composer, how can I modify bot code in Azure bot service(portal) to save conversation to Blob Storage?

Thank you,
Corridor1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Can you link to any tutorials or samples you've used? Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is GiftA's answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bot framework SDK still underlies your composer based project, so you can enable same logging solution in CSPROJ. Here are some [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-plugin) for extending the composer and the following document shows how to [eject the runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-add-custom-action) which basically makes a copy of the bots runtime on disk so you can modify it directly.